# SharePoint integration not working after TFS 2010 to TFS 2017 upgrade for old sites. TFSRedirect.aspx error

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

We upgraded a site from TFS 2010 to TFS 2017 to new infrastructure including the TFS, SQL, SharePoint and Reporting Services.
Everything is working ok except for old SharePoint portal sites.
They initially appeared to be working but were in fact being redirected to the old Reporting Services site.  We did tell TFS about the new SharePoint and Reporting using instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386320(VS.100).aspx
However, that still didn't resolve.  So we tried to add &tf:ClearCache=1 to the TFSRedirect URL thinking that maybe it was caching the old URI.  However, now whenever we try to access that portal all the webparts are broken and when we try to access anything with a TFSRedirect it gives an error.
Error=TF250008: This SharePoint site is not currently associated with a team project in Team Foundation Server.  However, we have done what we thought was requried (URL above).  What are we missing?

Comment: Have you considered just dropping the Sharepoint integration? It's no longer present in TFS 2018 and all of the features enabled by Sharepoint integration are implemented in a far better fashion within TFS itself.

Comment: The error message TF250008 indicates that you didn't configure team project portal successfully. Have you double check that, how to please follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sharepoint-dashboards/configure-or-add-a-project-portal  Besides you could also take a look at this [similar issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2451685/microsoft-sharepoint-project-portal-problems-with-microsoft-team-found) to see if it's helpful.